# Xamarin UWP compiling with .Net native tool chain causes run time exceptions

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, uwp, .net-native

I have a xamarin application that works fine until i check the "compiling with .Net native tool chain" in the project properties. I get following exceptions:

```
Exception thrown: 'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException' in Prism.Forms.dll
Exception thrown: 'StructureMap.StructureMapConfigurationException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll
```

Just to be clear the project builds with no issues and when i uncheck the checkbox the application runs fine.

If anyone has ran into this and has any ideas on how i can troubleshoot i would greatly appreciate it

Comment: It's hard to say where the issue is with the exception message. Please provide a [mcve] for more diagnosis.

Comment: It's likely caused by .NET Native tree shaking away something that is needed. If you stop on first chance exceptions (Debug > Windows > Exception Settings> check Common Language Runtime, run the program with the issue), it's likely that there's an unexpected issue there that will need to be addressed by modifying your rd.xml (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/net-native/runtime-directives-rd-xml-configuration-file-reference). Typical exceptions are FileNotFound, TypeLoad, MissingMetadata, etc. If you don't have any luck you can send me a mail at dotnetnative@microsoft.com.